# Parsing JSON file in Rails: extracting and mapping values to DB model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a JSON file the has a structure something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name" : {
      "Attribute" : " Value",
      "Attribute2" : " Value2",
      "Attribute3" : " Value3",
    }
   , "Name2" : {
    ...
    }
]
```

I'm trying to seed this file into a database table. I don't need all attribute:value pairs, so I need to map the ones I need to the `create` command in the loop. This is what I've attempted in the `seeds.rb` file:

```
json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(File.read("db/exercises.json"))

json.each_with_index do |e, index|

    Model.create!(
        name: e[0]
        )

end
```

What I essentially need to do is something like this:

```
Model.create!(
    name: e[0],
    attribute1: e[0][attribute1],
    attribute3: e[0][attribute3]
    )
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you show us a more realistic sample of your data file? It's not clear what you're trying to map to your model. For starters, you want `JSON.parse`, not `decode`, and you shouldn't be referencing `e[0]` - `e` is not an array.

Comment: I need to map the "Name" and the "Value" associated with the attributes to my database model. My model has columns for Name, Value, Value2, etc.

Comment: It looks like the braces in your example are mismatched. Is `{ ... repeat ... }` supposed to be the second element in the top-level array, rather than a sibling of `"Name"` (which is invalid syntax)?

Comment: My mistake, i meant to convey that the same structure repeats, fixed now

Comment: So does the array only have a single object in it, and the object contains a key/value pair for each record you want to insert in your DB?

Comment: Yes, the array has one object, and there are hundreds of "Name-x" : { ... } pairs. So I need to extract and map the "Name" itself, and some of the inner key-value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your confusion is around how to access your objects. `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode` parses your data into an array containing a Hash with keys `"Name"`, `"Name2"`, etc. [`Hash#each`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) yields pairs of `|key, value|` that you can use to populate your database. Your keys become `Model#name`, and then you can map the data's attributes to your model's.

```
data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(File.read("db/exercises.json"))
data = data[0] # Unwrap the Array

data.each do |name, attributes|
  Model.create!(
    name: name,
    column_one: attributes['one'],
    column_two: attributes['another one']
  )
end
```

If your file shares key names with your columns, Rails provides [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to easily pull out a subset.

```
> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.slice(:a, :c)
#=> {a: 1, c: 3}
```

Comment: What do I do if the attribute is composed of more than one word ?

Comment: Your model can't have multiple words in its columns, so you need to map those explicitly like `name`. Read up on Ruby Hashes, it sounds like you're missing that foundation.

Comment: That's right, but I only want to map some of the attributes. Would something like `.splice(column_name: "attribute1", column_name_2: "attribute3")` work ?

Comment: No, if you read the docs you'll see that `slice` accepts a list of key name you want out, not a hash. I've updated my example with the more explicit mapping you're after.